# manage an JSON response pushing in array or matching with a regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to manage the response of a ajax file thats give to me a JSON, something like this:

```
{ 
    "action": "register", 
    "error": "&#9;Please fill in all required fields.&#10;", 
    "newScreenName": "", 
    "invalidCredentials": "", 
    "missingFields": [ "email", "screenName", "passwd", "passwd2",
                       "fname", "lname", "profile", "zip", "country", ], 
    "errorFields": []
}
```

I have two option: or I find a way to push this in a obj so I can take the data I need like this: Obj.action , that will return "register" in this case. If this is not possible a way to match it with a regexp taking all I can found between the [ ] so then I can know what missingFields and errorFields I have.
I am working with javascript

I use this to take the response:
var text = $('*').text().trim()

that give to me this:

```
{\"action\": \"register\",
\"error\": \"&#9;Please fill in all required fields.&#10;\",
\"newScreenName\": \"\",
\"invalidCredentials\": \"\",
\"missingFields\": [\"email\", \"screenName\", \"passwd\", \"passwd2\", \"fname\", \"lname\", \"profile\", \"zip\", \"country\", ],
\"errorFields\": []}
```

so I use this to remove the \ : text = text.replace(/"/g, "'")

Thank you

Comment: Could you please post your JavaScript Code here ?

Answer (score 3):

And that magical function happens to be [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global%5fObjects/JSON/parse)

```
var data = JSON.parse(YOUR_JSON_HERE);
var action = data.action; //register
var missingFields = data.missingFields // [ "email", "screenName", "passwd", "passwd2", "fname", "lname", "profile", "zip", "country", ]
```

Comment: I tried : var jsonData = JSON.parse(text)but give me an error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token in object literal

Comment: @Scutto `text` should be a string. JSON is a string.

Comment: text is a string but .parse() still give me that error

Comment: @Scutto Then the JSON could possibly be deformed, like the trailing comma in the `missingFields` array.

Comment: I discover that using .parse() before the replace it works in the right way. thank you for the help